# command-line: nodeJS not working on double-pipelining

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line, pipe

I'm trying to execute my node app through a bash script using some pipes to have a nice formatted output:

```
node ~/app.js 2>&1 | grep -v "something" | grep --color -Ei "^|Error"
```

But I got a frozen output.

Everything is nice when I type `node ~/app.js | command_1`, the problem seems to appear when using `node ~/app.js | command_1 | command_2`.

No problem with other commands like `cat myscript.sh | command_1 | command_2`

I'm using node v0.10.15 and ubuntu 13.10 server.

**TL;DR**: No output from `node ~/app.js | command_1 | command_2`

How to handle this problem?

Say me if my question is not clear.

Comment: Try `grep`'s option `--line-buffered`.

Comment: Works fine, Thanks!


But have you any idea of what is exactly the problem on the node side?
I do not understand how buffering the output of grep solve the issue.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/